# What is the Vue.js equivalent of Express-Handlebars sections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I started a project using Express and Handlebars and then was encouraged to look at Vue.js. I am still at the stage of reading the docs but so far can't understand how to have layouts, partials and sections in Vue.js. I think a partial would be a component, but I'm lost how to have a layout with partials and sections that I can inject content into.

This is what I do using npm `express-handlebars` in a file called `baselayout.hbs`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {{> global/headcode }} <!-- partial view with code for the head tag. it has stuff like favicon links --->
    {{{_sections.pagemeta}}} <!-- page specific metadata injected here. this would be meta keywords description etc for a page/view --->
</head>
<body>
<div>
    {{> global/siteheader }} <!--- partial view for the site's header --->

    <div id="base-Container">
        <main id="base-Content" role="main">
            {{{ body }}} <!--- a page's main body content goes here --->
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
{{> sitefooter }} 
{{{_sections.pagescripts}}} <!-- section for page-specific scripts injected here --->
</body>
</html>
```

How could I setup something like the above in Vue.js that would also work with server-side rendering? I just need a base layout with header/footer components included but also sections into which page-specific content can go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SSR, you should look at Nuxt.js, Vapper, or one of the other SSR Vue frameworks.

That said, yes, you would use components for everything. Generally, you would have one component for your main layout, then one for each view, then individual components for each partial/section that you would then import into your views and/or main layout. So, for example, based on the above code:

Your main app layout:

```
// AppLayout.vue

<template>
  <div id="app-layout">
    <site-header />
    <router-view />
    <site-footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SiteHeader from './components/global/SiteHeader.vue'
import SiteFooter from './components/global/SiteFooter.vue'

export default {
  name: 'AppLayout',
  components: {
    SiteHeader,
    SiteFooter
  },
  meta: {
    // metatags and other head content can be modified using vue-meta or similar 
  }
}
</script>
```

Example 'partial' component:

```
// BaseContainer.vue

<template>
  <main id="base-container" role="main">
    <h1 class="title">{{ content.title }}</h1>
    <img :src="image" alt="" />
    <base-content v-html="content.body" />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import BaseContent from './components/content/BaseContent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'BaseContainer',
  components: {
    BaseContent
  },
  props: {
    content: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {}
      }
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Example view component:

```
// MyView.vue

<template>
  <div id="my-view">
    <base-container :content="content" :image="image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BaseContainer from './components/BaseContainer.vue'
import content from './data/myContent.json'
import image from './assets/myImage.jpg'

export default {
  name: 'MyView',
  components: {
    BaseContainer
  },
  data() {
    return {
      content,
      image
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You would then use `vue-router` to specify which view component to load based on the current URL.

Comment: I want to pass in a full view page than just a string like "this is my body copy" - is that possible?

Comment: How do you mean? The example I gave is just a string but it can be an entire object or it can be HTML content or a file or anything else you want to pass into and display in your component.

Comment: can you please give me a code example of loading a file instead of the string `'This is body copy'`

Answer (score 1):

**You probably need to use components and slots within your components.**

Yes you need to create a component for each of your partials. Each component would have a template.

Then you will have a main component that will put all of this together. Using the more granular components you already have (your partials).

Now if the template structure (html for each component) is coming from the server then you can prob use **slots** https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html which is a way VueJs allow components to receive custom markup when instantiating the components (see the example in the docs)

For the general layout and UI components of your app you may want to look at https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/layout which is a nice alternative to the more popular Vuetify.

Comment: But this doesn't touch on SSR. And you can't use a component in the `<head>` section of the page, either. It's a half answer. The real problem is that the question is too broad.

Comment: Yeah tbh haven't dealt with SSR in Vue, I'm transitioning myself into Vue but from an ExtJs bg.